# array_combine and associative result

Tags: php, yii

I am using YII framework

```
$job_status = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('count(*) as total_count, Image_status')
            ->from('AllDetail')
            ->where("JobID=:job_id",array(':job_id'=>$job_id))
            ->group('Image_status')
            ->queryAll();
$status_key = array();
$images = array();
foreach($job_status as $job){
    $imgstate = array_push($status_key,CompClass::statusMaster($job['Image_status']));
    $tot_img = array_push($images,$job['total_count']);
}
```

Status Master refers to a function in my component class

Which has

```
public static function statusMaster($status_code)
{
    switch($status_code)
    {
        case 0:
        $alias = 'QUEUE';
        break;
            case 1:
        $alias = 'PROCESSING';
        break;
            case 2:
        $alias = 'COMPLETED';
        break;

    }
            return $alias;
        }
```

Here is my view

```
<strong>Queued: <?php echo $job_status['QUEUE']; ?></strong><br />
<strong>Processing: <?php echo $job_status['PROCESSING']; ?></strong><br />
<strong>Completed: <?php echo $job_status['COMPLETED']; ?></strong><br />
```

The above script throws error if it doesn't have any status_code (i.e)

If image in database has `status_code 0 and 1` `but not 2` I am getting `undefined index completed`. Instead it should show as `0`.

Whether i can use exception handling of any other efficient method

Answer (score 0):

Set a value for each 'image_status' in the query, then saves you make the call to  "statusMaster($status_code)" function. Then you have the correct value in the $job object inside of foreach($job_status).

```
$job_status = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('count(*) as total_count, CASE Image_status
                                                    WHEN 0 THEN "QUEUE"
                                                    WHEN 1 THEN "PROCESSING"
                                                    WHEN 2 THEN "COMPLETED"
                                                    ELSE "DEFOULT VALUE"
                                                    END as Image_status ')
            ->from('AllDetail')
            ->where("JobID=:job_id",array(':job_id'=>$job_id))
            ->group('Image_status')
            ->queryAll();
```

In **view**:

```
<strong>Queued: <?php echo isset($job_status['QUEUE'])?  $job_status['QUEUE'] : ''; ?></strong><br />
<strong>Processing: <?php isset($job_status['PROCESSING'])?  $job_status['PROCESSING'] : ''; ?></strong><br />
<strong>Completed: <?php isset($job_status['COMPLETED'])?  $job_status['COMPLETED'] : '';?></strong><br />
```

Comment: Is this good idea to have `WHEN 0 THEN "QUEUE"` in query. Suppose i need to add other 10 status is it good.

Comment: If you have 10 different status and use it in many places in the application it is cleaner to have a function.

Comment: Yes thats what i did. But i am facing with the error above mentioned

Answer (score 0):

your trying to set the status according to its representing number right, try this:

```
<strong>Queued: <?php echo CompClass::statusMaster($job['Image_status']); ?></strong><br />
```

and for the undefined use isset() an !empty() to make sure you're dealing with valid variables.

thats all!